# Remove backgroundDimAmount from CameraPreview in DialogFragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I show a CameraPreview in a `FragmentDialog`. The problem is, because the dialog has a tinted background (`backgroundDimAmount`) to the content behind it, the `CameraPreview`

Is there anyway to remove this tint from the CameraPreview?

I can totally remove the background tint with:

```
getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

But that's not what I want. I want the background tint, just not on the CameraPreview

Answer (score 3):

set dim amount programming in your DialogFragment

```
@Override public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  Window w = getDialog().getWindow();
  //0 means transparent outside
  //1 means black outside
  w.setDimAmount(0f);
}
```